# trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt not being called on iPhone simulator in Xcode - works on iPad simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, ios-simulator, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

Recently updated Xcode to 13.4.1.

When I compile to any iPhone simulator, swiping a tableViewCell does not trigger trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt. Works fine on iPad simulator and on a real iPhone.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    // isn't getting this far on iPhone simulator!
    
    let contextItem1 = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Edit") {  (contextualAction, view, completionHandler) in
        self.edit(at: indexPath.adjustRowIndex())
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    

    contextItem1.backgroundColor = UIColor.HIIT.green
    
    let contextItem2 = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {  (contextualAction, view, completionHandler) in
        
        let row = self.data[indexPath.adjustRowIndex().row]
        self.alert(data: AlertDataObjects.delete(name: row.name), cancelCompletion: nil) {
            self.deleteRow(at: indexPath.adjustRowIndex())
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    }
    contextItem2.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
    
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem1, contextItem2])

    swipeActions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
    return swipeActions
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be happening because I was running Xcode in Rosetta mode (on an M1 MacBook).

**Finder > Applications > Control + Click Xcode > Get Info - Uncheck Open in Rosetta Mode checkbox.**

Rosetta Mode off: delegate behaviour as expected, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt method called and simulator working as expected
Rosetta Mode on: trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt method called once on very first run of app / cell swipe, and after that, method not called at all. (canEditRowAt is called normally)